# Operations with a created table MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 original tables (aliases: "TP", "NF" and "INF") and i did this join:

```
SELECT TP.SABOR, YEAR(NF.DATA_VENDA) AS ANO_VENDA, SUM(INF.QUANTIDADE) AS QUANTIDADE FROM 
itens_notas_fiscais AS INF INNER JOIN tabela_de_produtos AS TP
ON INF.CODIGO_DO_PRODUTO = TP.CODIGO_DO_PRODUTO 
INNER JOIN notas_fiscais AS NF
ON INF.NUMERO = NF.NUMERO
GROUP BY TP.SABOR, YEAR(NF.DATA_VENDA) HAVING ANO_VENDA = 2016
```

which returned me that:

[image]

After that I wanted to know the percentage of each value in the QUANTIDADE column in relation to the total, doing that code:

```
SELECT *, (AUX.QUANTIDADE/SUM(AUX.QUANTIDADE)) AS PORCENTAGEM FROM(
*previous code*) AS AUX
GROUP BY AUX.SABOR;
```

But this SUM function returned the same value for each row and not the sum of all columns, resulting in this:

[image]

I would like to have a result like this:

| Sabor | ANO_VENDA | QUANTIDADE | % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Açai | 2016 | 5 | 0.16 |
| Laranja | 2016 | 10 | 0.33 |
| Manga | 2016 | 15 | 0.5 |

Comment: [Creating a view](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-views-tutorial.aspx) is possibly the easiest way of handling this sort of situation - you can effectively create a virtual table from a query which can provide some useful isolation when queries start getting big.

Comment: please edit your question to show the output you want to get.  also please use text, not images

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: @ysth version 8.0.27

Comment: @ysth i would like SUM(AUX.QUANTIDADE) to return the sum of all the values of the column QUANTIDADE, from the created table AUX, which i used GROUP B, rather than the same value of each row